# YouTubeThumbnailView in List View

Tags: android, listview, youtube, thumbnails

I'm using the YouTube API to play videos from YouTube *(obviously)* which is working quite well so far. The issue I'm having is that I'm using a List View to display the different videos titles and thumbnails, which requires a custom adapter and the YouTubeThumbnailView.

Now the code I have works well enough in that it loads the thumbnails and stores them in the Map correctly, however when the views are recreated and the thumbnail needs to be retrieved from the Map again, it sometimes displays the wrong one and quite often duplicates.

Here's the adapter code:

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
    YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener{

Map<View, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> mLoaders;

public VideoListAdapter(final Context context, final List<Video> list, final int layoutResourceId) {
    mList = VideoManager.getInstance().getContentList();
    this.mLayID = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = context;
    mList = list;
    mLoaders = new HashMap<View, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mCurrentRow = convertView;
    PostHolder holder;
    String videoId = mList.get(position).videoId;

    if(mCurrentRow == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        mCurrentRow = inflater.inflate(mLayID, parent, false);

        holder = new PostHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)mCurrentRow.findViewById(R.id.list_content_title);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(mList.get(position).title);

        //Case 1 - Initalise the thumbnail
        holder.thumb = (YouTubeThumbnailView) mCurrentRow.findViewById(R.id.list_content_thumb);
        holder.thumb.setTag(videoId);
        holder.thumb.initialize(Utils.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        mCurrentRow.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (PostHolder) mCurrentRow.getTag();
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = mLoaders.get(holder.thumb);

        //Set the title
        Video post = mList.get(position);
        if(post != null){
            holder.txtTitle.setText(post.title);
        }

        if (holder.loader == null)
        {
            //Case 2 - Loader is currently initializing
           holder.thumb.setTag(videoId);
        } else
        {
            //Case 3 - The loader is already initialised
            holder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            holder.loader.setVideo(videoId);
        }
    }
    return mCurrentRow;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
    String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
    mLoaders.put(view, loader);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    loader.setVideo(videoId);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        if (errorDialog == null || !errorDialog.isShowing()) {
            //errorDialog = errorReason.getErrorDialog(, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            errorDialog.show();
        }
    } else {
        /*String errorMessage =
                String.format(getString(R.string.error_thumbnail_view), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    }
}

static class PostHolder
{
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumb;
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtTime;
}
```

I've read what I can of the documentation and I've taken a look at the sample applications but I haven't found anything that can help me. This might not be a problem with the YT API but a problem with the way I am storing the ImageViews.

If anyone can offer any assistance I'd be grateful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't save the YouTubeThumbnailLoader in your PostHolder class, but let all loaders handled by the mLoaders HashMap. As you realized in the comments, you need this HashMap to setup the loaders by the callbacks. Therefore change the else-part of your getView()-Method to this:

```
     } else {

        holder = (PostHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //Set the title
        Video post = mList.get(position);
        if(post != null){
            holder.txtTitle.setText(post.title);
        }

        // 2) and 3) The view is already created...
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = mLoaders.get(holder.thumbnailView);

        // ...and is currently being initialized. We store the current videoId in the tag.
        if (loader == null) {
            holder.thumbnailView.setTag(videoId);

        // ...and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId on the loader.
        } else {
            holder.thumbnailView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            loader.setVideo(videoId);

        }
    }
```

Your Post Holder class doesn't need the Loader:

```
 static class PostHolder
 {
   YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
   TextView txtTitle;
   TextView txtTime;
 }
```

Comment: Could I not remove the HashMap entirely by just placing the YouTubeThumbnailLoader in the holder as I have done, and then removing this line:

    YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = mLoaders.get(holder.thumbnailView);

Having done that it seems to speed up loading of the thumbnails since the thumbnail is retrieved with this line holder = (PostHolder) mCurrentRow.getTag(); Removing the need to search a HashMap.

Comment: Hmm, yeah as long as you only need the loader within the context of your PostHolder this should be no problem. In my case I also needed it   outside the getView()-Method and therefore as a class field of my adapter. I'll edit my answer to show both options.

Is the performance difference really that big? If yes, I'd consider to refactor my approach in my app ;)

Comment: Actually having just tried that I realised the error in my logic, storing the thumbnailLoader in the holder would be fine providing you could put it in there.

Since you need to wait until onInitializationSuccess is called before you can do anything with the loader, you no longer have access to the holder to store it. You could store it the second time the view is created with: holder.loader = mLoaders.get(holder.thumb); but that could increase the overhead.

Comment: As a bonus question to you, have you ever had to deal with this when you change orientation: MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@4266b068 that was originally bound here.

I'm thinking I might need to release the loaders from the map or do something with the PlayerView.

Comment: haha you're right, I edited the answer again. Didn't think of that myself... :)
And yes your bonus question rings a bell..I remember a for-loop over the HashMap, calling loader.release() on all existing loaders...but I haven't stumbled upon this exact error yet, sorry

Comment: maybe this example helps (search for "release"):
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java?r=b9d9565b17705d71a9c0093d8623c6b0c912e6d9

Comment: Saves lots of my time . Thanks